# How can I write a function in Python that normalize list, 1d,2d array, and data frames for arbitrary max and min?

Tags: python, normalization, data-mining

I am supposed to write a function that takes 4 arguments : trData, teData, minV, maxV. and return normalize for list, 1d,2d array, and data frame. I would be so grateful if you could assist me how to start and initiate .

Answer (score 0):

From your parameters of the function, it sounds like you have train and test data that you would like to min-max normalize.

If we assume you row-normalize, then you need to apply a normalization to each row of your input. the formula is then:

```
(value - min(row)) / (max(row) - min(row))
```

You can apply that in many different ways, for a dataframe you can do:

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x - x.min())/( x.max() - x.min()), axis = 1)
```

You can potentially change your input to dataframes and do it like that, or make similar apply for numpy.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I want to pass min and max as an argument. I mean I want the function to normalize with respect to every min and max that we pass as an argument, not to normalize just between 0 and 1